# Realm Migration Required without realm structure changes

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

I've made some fixes on my app which was at version 24 on playstore and I changed my version code from 24 to 25 (My realm version is the same as the build version code) . But didn't change nothing on realm structure, didn't add any field, neither remove any. But still I was asked to migrate from version 24 to 25, and i needed to add a weird looking code in a migration class like this:

```
    if (oldVersion == 24) {

        oldVersion++;
    }
```

This worked but it looked so strange to me since I didn't change anything, not even a query.

Anyone got any idea what could have triggered this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Realm version number is stored internally in the Realm file and that is used as the first check to trigger a migration.

Comment: But I always change my version number each time I release a new version, and Realm never asks for a migration as long as I don't change anything in Realm structure. That's why I think this is pretty weird